# Qt: Updating only changed rows in QTableView when Inserting/Removing rows in QAbstractTableModel

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to perform only a partial update on updated rows in my `QTableView` when I insert and remove rows of my `TableModel` (`QAbstractTableModel` inheriting).

When I perform my insertions I call my overridden `insertRows(row, count, QModelIndex())` which appends to my data structure within `beginInsertRows(parent, row, row + count - 1)` and `endInsertRows()`.

The table stays up to date during adds and removes but it looks like the signals emitted by the `beginInsertRows(..)` and `endInsertRows()` telling the view to update the entire table. A print statement inside my `TableModel::data()` reveals that the all cells of my table are being refreshed.

```
bool TableModel::insertRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent)
{
    if (row >= 0 && row <= file_records.size())
    {
        beginInsertRows(parent, row, row + count - 1);
        file_records.append(0);
        endInsertRows();

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

// when adding record 
int row = file_records.size();
if (insertRow(row))
{
    file_records[row] = file_record;
}

inline bool QAbstractItemModel::insertRow(int arow, const QModelIndex &aparent)
{ 
    return insertRows(arow, 1, aparent); 
}
```

Is there a way to tell the view to only update the new rows?

My update function emits `dataChanged()` on the affected indexes, and it successfully only updates relevant view data. But there doesn't seem to be a way around using the `begin*` and `end*` functions when I make structural changes.

Comment: You are right, you have to use `beginInsertRows()` and `endInsertRows()` in your case. Have you checked [the roles](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum) for which `data()` gets called (e.g. `Qt::DisplayRole`, `Qt::SizeHintRole`, ...)?

Comment: Yes, I am filtering out all but display role.

Comment: what do you mean by "filtering out"? I was asking about roles for which your overridden `data()` method gets called. Maybe try putting a `qDebug()` statement to print out the role inside `data()` to identify them...

Comment: Inside my data method I have a conditional that looks for a role that is Display Role. If and only if the role is Display Role then I return the appropriate cell value. If role is something else I return an empty QVariant(). Hence, I am "filtering out" all roles except the display role. The reason I know which cells are being accessed is because I used qDebug() inside the conditional to print the row and column currently being accessed, so I am certain they are DisplayRole.